# Python store video as hdf5 results in large file size

Tags: python, video, hdf5

I try to store a video clip frame by frame into a hdf5 file.
My code is working so far but I noticed, that compared to the source video file, the size of the hdf5 file is more than 10 times bigger.

**Input file**: avi 200 x 126px, duration: 16 minutes, size: **82 MB**

**Output file**: hdf5, gzip compression, compression = 9, size: **1 GB**

The code to store the frames is pretty simple:

```
import h5py
from skvideo.io import VideoCapture
frames = []
cap = VideoCapture('/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/video2H5Test/data/video_F100_scaled2.avi')
cap.open()

it = 0
while True:
    retval, image = cap.read()
    if image != None:
        frames.append(image)
        it += 1
        if (it % 1000 == 0):
            print('Processed %d frames so far' % (it))
    if not retval:
        break

with h5py.File('./test3.hdf5','w') as h5File:
    h5File.create_dataset('camera1',data=frames,compression='gzip',compression_opts=9)
```

As you can see I already use gzip to compress my dataset.

Is there any other way to save memory consumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who came across the same problem:

Initialize your dataset with the first image:

```
myDataSet = myFile.create_dataset('someName', data=image[None, ...], maxshape=(
                None, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]), chunks=True)
```

To add an image simply resize the whole dataset:

```
myDataSet.resize(myDataSet.len() + 1, axis=0)
myDataSet[myDataSet.len() - 1] = image
```

Comment: You forgot to add the compression. Without it the file size is the same as creating separate datasets for each frame but takes 10+ times longer

Answer (score 0):

What is your chunking scheme in the output hdf file? Compression is done by chunks, so considering that most of the information in video does not change from frame to frame, you should get much better compression ratio when different frames exist in the same chunk. I can try it out if you provide sample video file.

Comment: Right now there is no chunking. Is there any way to save the dataset in my while loop? In case of a larger video file the frames list could be very large.

Comment: Yes you can write hdf file in parts. This is actually one of the benefits of this file format.

Comment: @kakk11: Could you look at the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46278714/how-to-compress-the-data-that-saved-in-hdf5? I have same issue as above